# The use of conditionals

Tags: conditionals

1 If I win this competition, I will be buying cars

2 If I win this competition, I will buy cars

3 If she arrives, I will be waving at her

4 If she arrives, I will wave at her

5 If I won the competiton I would be buying cars

6 If I won the competition I would buy cars

Does 1 and 2 both mean after my triumph? 3 at the moment of her arrival and 4 after? 5 and 6 both after?

Comment: None of your sentences sound natural. For one thing. we don't normally buy several cars at a time (like buying eggs or apples), so you would say something like "I will buy two cars" or "I will buy a car for each of my family". Common sense leads the reader to understand that the prize for the competition must be a large sum of money so naturally the purchases will come after the win.

Comment: @Kate Bunting. Sorry it's my fault. I didn't express what I want to know. I don't really care if it's natural. I want to know what  the continouos aspect means.  For instance "if I won, I would be buying a car. Does it mean" at the moment of winning I'm in the middle of buying a car? If so why this example is correct "if you don't change your mind, we will be protesting". People told me that the continuous form here shows that it may be repeated or take some time not that we start the protest before the decision.

Comment: You don't normally use present continuous to express the consequence or result, although you can use it to express something that's happening at the same time. "If you come to my house after 8 pm, I will be watching television" is OK because you're watching TV anyway and it's not caused by you coming to my house. But it doesn't mean that I will watch TV *because of* your coming to my house, so you would say "If you come to my house after 8 pm, we will watch television" (although that's not very natural).

Comment: @Stuart F. Why is this fine then "If you don't change your mind, we will be protesting"?

Comment: Daba, you say "I don't care if it's natural", but it's difficult to tell you "what a sentence means" if it's something that no-one would ever say! It was explained to you that _If you don't change your mind, we will be protesting_ is an acceptable sentence, but that doesn't mean that the same grammatical construction has to make sense for all verbs. We _sometimes_ use the future continuous for a promise or threat - this applies to _we will be protesting_ but **not** to _I shall be buying a car_.

Comment: @Kate Bunting. Thank you. I'd like to ask you how you understand these examples? What is the difference between them? If it's possible except for which is natural and which isn't please write if there is a difference in meaning.                                
  1 If I win this competition, I will be buying cars

2 If I win this competition, I will buy cars  5 If I won the competiton I would be buying cars

6 If I won the competition I would buy cars

Comment: "If she comes to visit him, I will be doing all I can to destroy her reputation". Is this fine? Seems lie a threat. Natives understand it after she comes no before right?

Comment: I would understand all four to mean that winning the competition will (prediction) or would (conditional) enable you to buy two or more cars - but, as explained above, I would find them all a strange way to express the idea.